# How can I change def to something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I always type in `function something():`. Is their any way to change `def` to `function`? I know this sounds like a silly question, but I would really appreciate any answers.

If their is something like that, can you also change `print` or `input`? For example:

```
name = question("What is your name? ")
answer(f"Hi {name}!")
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change keywords like `def`. For the other two, you can simply use the commands `question = input` and `answer = print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for `print` and `input`:

```
question = input
answer = print
```

You can call them like this:

```
question("What is your name? ")
answer(f"Hi {name}!")
```

As for changing `def` you probably would have to modify the source code of your python installation and recompile it to do something like that. That would be a very bad practice as it would then make it your python installation incompatible with almost 100% of python code that can be downloaded and run.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489603/defining-aliases-for-keywords-in-python) for more info on changing `def` to `function`